# Embed JavaScript functions with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to dynamically output a menu tree with a database.The code doesn't seem to record the JavaScript functions or write properly. Do anyone have an idea?

```
<? php
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='dtree.js'></script>";

$db = new MyDB();

$sql =<<<EOF
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY FROM ITEM;
EOF;

$ret = $db->query($sql);
$i = 1;
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";         

    echo    "d = new dTree('d');";
    echo    "d.add(0,-1,'Introduction', 'index.html','','','img/blue.gif');";       
    while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
        echo "d.add( " . $i . ", 0, '" . $row['CATEGORY'] . "', );";
        $i++;
    }
echo "document.write(d);";

echo "</script>";
$db->close();

echo "Operation done successfully\n";

?>
```

Comment: What is actually being written to the browser?

Comment: what is the output? is that correct? Do you get any javascript errors? Or maybe even php errors?

Comment: Only "Operation done successfully" is written.

There are no javascript or php errors. :/

Comment: So, in that case, does your query returns rows? Have you tried to run the query directly on the sql server? And have you looked into the source code? as ofcourse you know that javascript is never being outputted in the browser as a visual thing...

Comment: @grirgio yes, I've tried the same Query in purely php and it works properly. Two rows are printed.

Comment: ok, if the only difference between the script which _does_ print rows and this one is that you now let it output javascript, you should 1) see the javascript if you look in the document source and 2) most probably there is something wrong with your javascript... As for a starter, the first line in the while loop you omit the last parameter of the `dTree.add` function. Fix that, then create us a fiddle of the javascript output.

Comment: @giorgio Thanks for the heads up! I misread the code and, accordingly, deleted my comment.

Comment: @giorgio it works! It seems like that last parameter omit messed things up somehow. Thanks Alot! This took me 6 hours to resolve. :)

Can I credit you in some way? I'm new to stackoverflow. :)

Comment: You should never write javascript with php, that's a nonsense, even if it's possible and that many people do it.

Comment: sure, I've added it as an answer, you could accept it ;) thanks! and glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop, you omitted the last parameter of the `dTree.add` button, check the first line in the while loop:

```
while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
    echo "d.add( " . $i . ", 0, '" . $row['CATEGORY'] . "', );";
    $i++;
}
```

You should either remove the comma (`,`), or add a parameter value. So both examples below would be correct.

```
echo "d.add( " . $i . ", 0, '" . $row['CATEGORY'] . "', '');";
echo "d.add( " . $i . ", 0, '" . $row['CATEGORY'] . "');";
```

To make it a bit more clear, the first line below is how your javascript looks like right now, the other two are examples of valid javascript that should be outputted.

```
d.add(1, 0, 'A string', ); // NOT correct, see the last comma
d.add(1, 0, 'A string', ''); // correct, by adding an empty string, BUT LOOK IN THE DOCS FOR THE RIGHT PARAMETER TYPE
d.add(1, 0, 'A string'); // Also correct, no fourth parameter
```